# Cloudflare cache is causing issue with loading

Tags: firebase, caching, cloudflare

We have a web application running on firebase hosting and cached on Cloudflare on top. It has been running fine but lately the content stops loading on the frontend? I have to purge all content on Cloudflare for it to start working again?

What is the issue here? Can somebody please guide?